# How to grab data from AlertDialog inside Custom Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have a Custom ListView that displays a TextView. When this TextView is clicked an AlertDialog pops-up with a multiple-choice selection checkbox. This data is stored inside of a boolean object.

My question is this, how do I grab this boolean object that is stored within the Custom ListView class?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could save it to shared preference to make it easy. Another way is to create  a callback/interface for it.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, You have a list view. A list item contains a string for textView inside the list item.  A list item has a property or something that can be changed from dialog which displays when the user clicked on the listItem.

So you have List or ArrayList for the listView structure should be like this.

```
class ListViewModel {
    private String text;
    private boolean checkBox1;
    ...
    }
```

When the user changes the checkbox value and at the positive button click of dialog, you pass the checkbox boolean and the position (via interface) to the parent. you have to update the list to save the changes. For that you get the object with the position from the List or ArrayList and update the structure with boolean. And then you need to update the listView to update the view.